# parallelizing C++ code with MPI_send and MPI_recv

Tags: c++11, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a parallel code, but I don't understand if it works correctly in parallel.
I have two vectors A and B whose elements are matrices defined with a proper class.
Since the matrices in the vectors are not primitive type I can't send these vectors to other ranks through MPI_Scatter, so I have to use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. Also, rank 0 has only a coordination role: it sends to the other ranks the blocks they should work with and collects the results at the end, but it does not participate to the computation.

The solution of the exercise is the following:

```
// rank 0 sends the blocks to the other ranks, which compute the local
// block products, then receive the partial results and prints the global
// vector
if (rank == 0)
{
    // send data
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < N_blocks; ++j) 
    {
        int dest = j / local_N_blocks + 1;
        // send number of rows
        unsigned n = A[j].rows();
        MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        // send blocks
        MPI_Send(A[j].data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(B[j].data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    // global vector
    std::vector<dense_matrix> C(N_blocks);

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < N_blocks; ++j) 
    {
        int root = j / local_N_blocks + 1;
        // receive number of rows
        unsigned n;
        MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, root, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        // initialize blocks
        dense_matrix received(n,n);
        // receive blocks
        MPI_Recv(received.data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, root, 5,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        // store block in the vector
        C[j] = received;
     }
     // print result
     print_matrix(C); 
}
    
    // all the other ranks receive the blocks and compute the local block
    // products, then send the results to rank 0
}
else
{
        // local vector
        std::vector<dense_matrix> local_C(local_N_blocks);
        // receive data and compute products
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < local_N_blocks; ++j) 
        {
            // receive number of rows
            unsigned n;
            MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            // initialize blocks
            dense_matrix local_A(n,n); dense_matrix local_B(n,n);
            // receive blocks
            MPI_Recv(local_A.data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(local_B.data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            // compute product
            local_C[j] = local_A * local_B; 
         }
         // send local results
         for (unsigned j = 0; j < local_N_blocks; ++j) 
         {
            // send number of rows
            unsigned n = local_C[j].rows();
            MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            // send block
            MPI_Send(local_C[j].data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
         }
}
```

In my opinion, if `local_N_blocks= N_blocks / (size - 1);`  is different from 1, the variable `dest` doesn't change value at every loop iteration. So, after the first iteration of the "sending loop", the second time that rank 0 faces

```
MPI_Send(A[j].data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(B[j].data(), n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

it has to wait that the operation  `local_C[j] = local_A * local_B`  of the previous j has been completed so the code doesn't seem to me well parallelized.
What do you think?

Comment: What is the instruction `{"for loop for rank 0 to receive the results from others ranks"}` supposed to do?

Comment: After computing the product, ranks different from 0 have to send back to rank 0 the solution. For simplicity I skipped that part of code

Comment: Could you fix your indentation? This is unreadable. I don't want to waste time in figuring out what braces belong together.

Comment: Done, I also added the previous omitted part of code. @VictorEijkhout